# No package 'tokyocabinet' found when install duc

Tags: linux

when I using this command to install duc:

```
wget -c https://github.com/zevv/duc/releases/download/1.4.4/duc-1.4.4.tar.gz
tar -zxvf duc-1.4.4.tar.gz
cd duc-1.4.4
./confugure
```

it give me tips:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (tokyocabinet) were not met:

No package 'tokyocabinet' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables TC_CFLAGS
and TC_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

then I install tokyocabinet package like this:

```
[root@uat-k8s-01 duc-1.4.4]# yum install tokyocabinet
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package tokyocabinet-1.4.48-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

but it still give not install package tips. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No package 'tokyocabinet' found

This means "no package config file" `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/tokyocabinet.pc` was found.

Solution : `# yum install tokyocabinet-devel`

I.e. all libraries used for building applications / compilation must be `(lib)[name]-devel`

Answer (score 1):

Before compile and install duc,you should install dependency package, if you using centos,should do like this:

```
sudo yum install pango-devel cairo-devel tokyocabinet-devel -y
sudo yum install ncurses-devel -y
```